# Using Pandas DataFrames is there a way to break a row into multiple rows based on if each column contains a value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe with columns A B C D E F and 3 rows:

```
[1,100,null,100,null,"cat"]
[2,null,50,null,50,"dog"]
[3,100,null,null,100,"cow"]
```

I am needing to find a way to go through each row and based on if there is a value in columns B C D E, break each value out into its own cloned row, with only 1 value being present per row.

Expected result:

```
[1,100,null,null,null,"cat"]
[1,null,null,100,null,"cat"]
[2,null,50,null,null,"dog"]
[2,null,null,null,50,"dog"]
[3,100,null,null,null,"cow"]
[3,null,null,null,100,"cow]
```

Have searched all over and did not find any good solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, one way:

```
df.melt(['A','F'])\
  .dropna()\
  .reset_index()\
  .pivot(index=['index','A','F'], columns='variable',  values='value')\
  .reset_index()\
  .drop(['index'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
variable  A    F      B     C      D      E
0         1  cat  100.0   NaN    NaN    NaN
1         3  cow  100.0   NaN    NaN    NaN
2         2  dog    NaN  50.0    NaN    NaN
3         1  cat    NaN   NaN  100.0    NaN
4         2  dog    NaN   NaN    NaN   50.0
5         3  cow    NaN   NaN    NaN  100.0
```

Another way:

```
df.set_index(['A', 'F'])\
  .stack()\
  .reset_index()\
  .set_index(['A','F','level_2'], append=True)[0]\
  .unstack()\
  .reset_index()\
  .drop('level_0', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
level_2  A    F      B     C      D      E
0        1  cat  100.0   NaN    NaN    NaN
1        1  cat    NaN   NaN  100.0    NaN
2        2  dog    NaN  50.0    NaN    NaN
3        2  dog    NaN   NaN    NaN   50.0
4        3  cow  100.0   NaN    NaN    NaN
5        3  cow    NaN   NaN    NaN  100.0
```

This is some pretty detailed dataframe reshaping.

Comment: Ok I got this partially working, only problem is my data has 0's in it which is causing it to create rows for 0's. That is a problem with my data though.

I ended up having to do df = pd.melt(df,['A','F'] ... as it would not let me just do df.melt(['A','F']).

Thanks for the guidance @Scott

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? df.melt was introduced in version 1.1.0.  If this answer helped you, would please kindly [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: pandas version 1.1.5

Answer (score 0):

Scott's first answer worked for me, with slight modification:

```
df = pd.melt(df,['A','F']\
  .dropna()\
  .reset_index()\
  .pivot(index=['index','A','F'], columns='variable',  values='value')\
  .reset_index()\
  .drop(['index'], axis=1)
```